# Structuring Nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a fetch api call which returns a really large array full of books and associated information, from which I only need the title, author, and associated passages. In `componentDidMount()` I am trying to grab the these values, and push them into a new array, structured in a way that makes sense for my project.

I am successfully grabbing and pushing the values, but I'm not able to maintain the nested structure. I would like the book title and author at the top, and then have the passages in a nested array associated with the book. My current code just pushes everything to same level, with no nesting.

In the code below, I would essentially like `this.state.dummyBooks` and `this.state.booksStructured` to be identical.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/schrdr/bz3f4pvj/)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dummyBooks: [
                {
                    title: "book title one",
                    author: "book author one",
                    passages: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            passage: "this is a passage",
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            passage: "this is another passage",
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    title: "book title two",
                    author: "book author two",
                    passages: [
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            passage: "this is a third passage",
                        },
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            passage: "this is yet another passage",
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
            booksStructured: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.state.dummyBooks.map(bookObject => {
            this.state.booksStructured.push({
                bookTitle: bookObject.title,
                bookAuthor: bookObject.author,
            });

            bookObject.passages.map(passageObject => {
                this.state.booksStructured.push({
                    passageID: passageObject.id,
                    passageText: passageObject.passage,
                });
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.booksStructured);
        return <div>check the console</div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Comment: it will be helpful, if you can paste the structure of object from the api.

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the required keys from `this.state.dummyBooks` and push it to the `this.state.booksStructured`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    for(const {title, author, passages} of this.state.dummyBooks){
        this.state.booksStructured.push({title:title,author:author,passages:passages});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to set `this.state.booksStructured` as your looping through `this.state.dummyBooks`, create an array based on the mapping values in `this.state.dummyBooks`, creating variables and assigning the updated key/value pairs accordingly. When that's finished use `this.setState({...})` to assign the new array to `this.state.booksStructured`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        dummyBooks: [
            {
            'title': 'book title one',
          'author': 'book author one',
          'passages': [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'passage': 'this is a passage'
            }, {
                'id': 2,
              'passage': 'this is another passage'
            }
          ]
        }, {
            'title': 'book title two',
          'author': 'book author two',
          'passages': [
            {
                'id': 3,
                'passage': 'this is a thridpassage'
            }, {
                'id': 4,
              'passage': 'this is yet another passage'
            }
          ]
        }   
        ],
      booksStructured: [],
    }

  }

    componentDidMount() {
    var booksStructured = this.state.dummyBooks.map(bookObject => {
    var obj = {}
    var {title, author, passages} = bookObject

    obj['bookTitle'] = title
    obj['bookAuthor'] = author

      passages = passages.map(x=>{
        var passageObj = {}
        passageObj['passageID'] = x.id
        passageObj['passageText'] = x.passage  
        return passageObj
      });

    obj['passages'] = passages
    return obj
    })

  this.setState({
    booksStructured
  })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.booksStructured);
    return (
      <div>
        check the console
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/c4qaenbp/5/).

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the code in your `componentDidMount` method, you should notice that what you're actually doing is iterating over `dummyBooks` and pushing an object containing only the book author and title into the `booksStructured` array before pushing an object containing only the passage id and text into the `booksStructured` array. Hence, the resulting array of alternating book then passage objects.

Instead, you would want to create one object containing both book and passage information before pushing it into the `booksStructured` array. You should also not that it's advised to use `setState()` in favor of `this.state.push()`:

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable. [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)

and you should generally not call `setState()` in a loop because

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setState)

With that in mind, your solution should look something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const structuredBooks = [];

  this.state.dummyBooks.map(bookObject => {
    // Iterate over each passage, returning a new object with only
    // the wanted fields from each passage object
    const structuredPasssages = bookObject.passages.map(passage => {
      passageID: passageObject.id,
      passageText: passageObject.passage,
    });

    // Construct a structured book object using the new passages
    const structuredBook = {
      bookTitle: bookObject.title,
      bookAuthor: bookObject.author,
      passages: structuredPassages,
    };

    // Push the structured book into "structuredBooks"
    structuredBooks.push(structuredBook);
  });

  // Update state with the complete structuredBooks array
  this.setState({ booksStructured: structuredBooks });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map to loop through the object and return the structure you want.

```
const booksStructured = apiData.map(book => {
  return {
    title: book.title,
    author: book.author,
    passages: book.passages
  };
});
```

Please don't modify state variables directly, like

```
this.state.booksStructured.push({ title:title,author:author, passages:passages});
```

Save the value in a local variable and update state using `.setState()`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script>

const apiData = [
  {
    title: 'book title one',
    author: 'book author one',
    more: 'more',
    xtra: 'tets',
    year: 2030,
    passages: [
      {
        id: 1,
        passage: 'this is a passage',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        passage: 'this is another passage',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'book title two',
    author: 'book author two',
    more: 'more',
    xtra: 'tets',
    year: 2000,
    passages: [
      {
        id: 1,
        passage: 'this is a passage',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        passage: 'this is another passage',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'book title three',
    author: 'book author three',
    more: 'more',
    xtra: 'tets',
    year: 2001,
    passages: [
      {
        id: 1,
        passage: 'this is a passage',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        passage: 'this is another passage',
      },
    ],
  },
];
  
</script>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      dummyBooks: [
        {
          title: "book title one",
          author: "book author one",
          passages: [
            {
              id: 1,
              passage: "this is a passage"
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              passage: "this is another passage"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "book title two",
          author: "book author two",
          passages: [
            {
              id: 3,
              passage: "this is a third passage"
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              passage: "this is yet another passage"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      booksStructured: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const booksStructured = apiData.map(book => {
      return {
        title: book.title,
        author: book.author,
        passages: book.passages
      };
    });

    this.setState({
      booksStructured: booksStructured
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.booksStructured);
    return <div>check the console</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```